# Swift 5 imagePickerController not displaying camera image

Tags: camera, uiimagepickercontroller, swift5, xcode13

camera display problem

Hi all,

I am new to Swift so please bear with my as I try to explain my problem.

I am writing an App in XCode 13 that is supposed to take a photo and display it in a UIImageView simply named "ImageResult".

The following two functions perform the required tasks:

`// Calls Camera (Works)`

`@objc private func TakePhoto(_ sender: Any) {`

`let picker = UIImagePickerController()`

`picker.sourceType = .camera`

`picker.allowsEditing = true`

`picker.delegate = self`

`present(picker, animated: true)`
`}`

`// Display Image From Camera (Doesn't work)`

`func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {`

`ImageResult.image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage`

`picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

`}`

The problem I am experiencing is that the imagePickerController does not display the camera image after the photo is taken. The info.plist has been updated with all the correct permissions and I have even gone to the extent of changing the source to picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary which does actually display the image.

Not sure if anyone else has experienced this problem and knows the answer but I really appreciate any response even suggestions as I feel as though I have exhausted all avenues. Thanks in advance for any help.

Matty.

Answer (score 0):

its late but maybe helped someone else

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    ImageResult.image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage
    
}
```